Manage PWA notification permissions via policies in Chrome Android
I created a PWA with web push notifications. The problem is the first time when an end user browses to the PWA he/she has to consent to receive notifications from this site. The popup looks like this:

Via the Settings of Chrome Android (Settings > Privacy and security > Site settings > Notifications) this can be preconfigured and the user will not receive the popup to allow that permission anymore. This seems the way to go in an entreprise context.

I don't find a way to populate this allowed sites list in Chrome Android via policies. Can this be done via policy, make it managed in a central way by an endpoint mobility management solution like Soti Mobicontrol or Intune?

Yes. Chrome has an immense amount of Managed Configurations available that you can manipulate if the app is approved as a Managed Play app for the Android Enterprise devices under management and you configure the Managed Configuration payload for that app. Any Android Enterprise EMM should be capable of this functionality as it is a baseline requirement for AE.
